# Is "firebase serve" just a plan vanilla dev server?

Tags: firebase, webpack, webpack-dev-server, firebase-hosting

Is `firebase serve`, the development server for Firebase, just a plain vanilla web server that serves files over HTTP, or does it do something special for Firebase apps?

More specifically, is there any reason to use `firebase serve` in development if it's more convenient in my situation to use another development web server (e.g., `webpack-dev-server` or a local Apache or IIS)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `firebase serve` command in the Firebase CLI interprets the instructions in your `firebase.json` file and serves the web site based on those.

If you're using another local dev server, you'll have to make sure it follows the same rules. That's typically not hard, but it somewhat of a hassle to ensure the `firebase.json` and configuration of the dev server stay in sync.

Comment: Which rules have to be followed?